# Issue refreshing file links intermittently with Scandir

Tags: php

I am using a a very simple code to pull file names and turn them into downloadable links on a files page.
It does work alot of the time. but for no reason it will just stop updating the list even if you add or remove items from the directory. Anyone experienced issues like this? Or have a decent alternative I could use.

```php
$dir = './wp-content/uploads/files';
$path = 'https://www.mainstaycomputing.com/wp-content/uploads/files/';

$files = scandir($dir);

// Sort in ascending order - this is default
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') {
        continue;
    }
       
    echo "<a href='" . $path . $file . "'>" . $file . "</a><br>";
        
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue, but it sounds like you expect the list to automatically update when you add or remove a file from the directory? If so, that's because PHP is done once the page is rendered. There is no magic happening to automatically update the page. You might use ajax or something to check for updates every few seconds and update a section of the page, but you cannot do this with PHP alone.

Comment: Hi Bryan, Not automatically refresh, I will refresh the page myself and the list still does not update. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That is strange. Do you have the files that don't show up opened? Also, can you verify PHP has read access on those missing files?